# How many different phone numbers are possible with 2 certain numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Assume all telephone numbers are 10 digits long, consisting of a 3-digit area code, then a 3-digit "exchange" number, followed by a 4-digit number. How many telephone numbers have no 0 in the area code and no 9 in the final 4-digit number?

I want to say the answer is $8^{10}$, but will that account for 0 also being the second or third number in the area code and 9 being the second, third or fourth number?

Comment: What have you tried? Posting homework questions with no context or attempt is not likely to be met with enthusiasm. In order to receive less downvotes, please consider using MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's work with the area code first consisting of 3-digits. If we had no constraint, then the total possible number of area codes is clearly $10^3 = 1000$ (starting from 000 up till 999).

Since no $0$ is allowed in the Area code ($AAA$), then we have nine allowed digits, hence a total number of area codes equal to $9^3$. So,
$$\text{Total number of area codes} = 9^3$$

Similarly, the last digits has no 9 and using the same reasoning above, the total is 
$$\text{Total number of last 4-digits codes} = 9^4$$

The exchange number is left intact (no constraints) so:
$$\text{Total number of last exchange numbers} = 10^3$$

So, the total number of possible phone numbers will be $9^3 \times 9^4 \times 10^3$

Comment: I get it now thank you for the thorough explanation!

Comment: If you found the explanation useful, you could mark the answer as correct so as to assist further readers.

Answer (score 0):

- $9^3$ for the area code ( no zero)
- $10^3$ for the exchange
- $9^4$ for the last 4 digits (no 9)

Total $= 9^7 \cdot 10^3$

Comment: Ohh now I understand! Thank you!